# Issue publishing .net core 3.1 with react application to IIS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I am trying to publish a .net core 3.1 with react application to IIS.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to publish the application, with the self-contained option. Everything publishes correctly.  Then i copy the files to the production server and run npm install in the wwwroot/project_name/ClientApp directory.

Once the application is published and node_modules installed, i try to access the site in a browser and receive the following errors in the browser devel tools:

> GET   http://localhost:9000/project_name/static/css/main.6ee213d7.chunk.css
> Response: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
> GET   http://localhost:9000/project_name/static/js/2.1881f413.chunk.js
> Response: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
>
> GET   http://localhost:9000/project_name/static/js/main.59fc77d5.chunk.js
> Response: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

I also see the following errors in the browser console:

> The stylesheet
> http://localhost:9000/project_name/static/css/2.5d15527e.chunk.css was
> not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
>
> The script from
> “http://localhost:9000/project_name/static/js/main.59fc77d5.chunk.js”
> was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid
> JavaScript MIME type.
>
> The stylesheet
> http://localhost:9000/project_name/static/css/main.6ee213d7.chunk.css
> was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
>
> The script from
> “http://localhost:9000/project_name/static/js/2.1881f413.chunk.js” was
> loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid
> JavaScript MIME type.

The Url is incorrect.  I have tried adding "homepage": "http://localhost:9000/project_name" and "homepage": "." to package.json but neither work.

> http://localhost:9000/favicon.ico

Looking on the developer tools Network tab.  I see a blocked request:

> GET http://localhost:9000/

Everything else is returning "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

I have verified that javascript is enabled.

I have installed the .NET Core hosting bundle on the target server.

Here is the Program.cs file:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                    webBuilder.UseIIS();
                });
    }
```

Can someone please help me get this working with IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with settings in startup.cs i was able to get this to run. Here are the changes i made in Startup: ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
```

Configure: I removed this:

```
app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { RequestPath = "/ClientApp/build" });
```

and added this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
```

After these changes i followed the same steps as above. Published the app locally, copied it to production server and ran npm install. It worked this time!